# cakephp - get table names and its column details

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

Does anyone knows how to get table name from model name? Also I want to get all column names and its types of that model/table name. Is it possible to get such details of given model name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Table Name**

To get the table, see

```
$this->Model->table
```

Or check the model for the class variable `$useTable`. If that's undefined, then you can infer it from the name of the model:

```
$tableName = Inflector::tableize($this->Model->alias);
```

See the [Inflector documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Inflector.html) for similarly useful methods.

**Columns**

Take a look at the [schema](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_schema) method of the Model class. For example:

```
var_dump($this->Model->schema());
```

Comment: I think for table name, you can just use $this->Model->table

Comment: So you can! nice :) Included in answer, left Inflector stuff in because it's still handy to know

Comment: In order to include the table prefix ready to be used for a raw query you will have to call the dbo source model: $this->getDataSource()->fullTableName($this)