# CakePHP 2 - Deriving table name of model within Behavior

Tags: cakephp, model, behavior, cakephp-2.x

Whats the usual practice in getting a behavior (linked to multiple models) to build filters for SQL queries, and then read the table that belongs to that model?

I have a Behavior function which is meant to do a database query with certain SQL conditions.  I currently pass in the $this->request->data.

I have issues building the SQL conditions because i'm not sure how to **derive the name of the table** (that corresponds to the model). See below for example, I want to change "**BillingCenterDetail**" which is the table name (and also the model name), **to something generic** I can use across different models. I want this table name to be derived automatically based on the model name. I'm not sure if i can use the $model reference for that.

```
public function saveWithTimeConstraintCheck(Model $model, $data) {


    //FIND ALL RECORDS THAT OVERLAP
    $overlapfilter = array(                                          
                        'BillingCenterDetail.billing_center_id    =' => $data['BillingCenterDetail']['billing_center_id'],
                        'BillingCenterDetail.startdate    <=' => $data['BillingCenterDetail']['enddate'],
                        'BillingCenterDetail.enddate      >=' => $data['BillingCenterDetail']['startdate']
                        );
```

... after building the filter, I can use $model->find to execute the query, this should be OK because its generic.

```
    $overlapresults = $model->find('all', array('conditions' => $overlapfilter));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question.

And actually to build filter conditions, I needed name of the model, not the name of the table, because the name of the table is a plural name with the "S" at the end.

I used 
$Model->name
From:
[CakePHP: get current model name in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529431/cakephp-get-current-model-name-in-a-controller)

For table names i found out u can also use 
$this->Model->table
[cakephp - get table names and its column details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709743/cakephp-get-table-names-and-its-column-details)

Comment: It is usually safer to use `$Model->alias` since this will respect the names assigned to models referenced through associations. When this isn't the case, `alias` is the same as `name` so it works just as well in the default case.